# How to add in Twig two translation fields in a bootstrap label

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, twig

I want to add in Twig in a bootstrap from label twee translations fields. For example "business" (first translation) "/" (fixed char) "private" (second translation field). So it wil show like "Business / Private".

I used the following code for single field, is it possible to add more?

```
{{ form_label(form.business, 'business'|trans, {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concat you two strings with "~". I tested this with "capitalize" filter, but it should work in a similar fashion for "trans". I tried two syntaxes

```
{{ form_label(form.bussness, ('business'|trans)~"/"~('private'|trans), {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}
```

and

```
{{ form_label(form.business, null, {
    'label': ('business'|trans)~"/"~('private'|trans),
    'label_attr': {'class': 'foo'}
}) }}
```